# Entity framework update of row version in a predefined order

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, rowversion

I am using C#, EF and SQL Server and have few tables with parent-child relationship. There are more than 2 but in this example I will use only 2 for simplicity.

**Table Book**

```
Id
DateModified
RowVersion
```

**Table Page**

```
Id
BookId - this is foreign key to Book.Id
RowVersion
```

When any page/pages are updates I need to update `DateModified` in Book table.

We are using `RowVersion` to keep track of changes, since it's unique value I want to always be able to get the latest changes for each book by simply doing something like

```
SELECT * FROM Page
WHERE RowVersion > Book.RowVersion
```

But in order to do this I need to make sure that `RowVersion` in `Book` table is ALWAYS updated before `RowVersions` in `Pages`.

In my EDM layer I currently have something like this:

```
class Page
{
  void OnPageChanged() //this is hooked to OnPropertyChanged
  {
     this.Book.UpdateDateModified(DataTime.Now);
  }
}
```

Doing this results in page being updated first and its RowVersion is updated first too after the transaction commits. Which is not what I need.

Question, if I will move `OnPageChanged()` to be handling `OnPropertyChanging` event instead - will this guarantee the consistency? Is it `OnPropertyChanged` that dictates the order the updates happen in sql generated by EF? Any other suggestions for this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this is possible. I cannot try it now but I have real doubts that you can compare timestamps (`RowVersion`) in Linq query. It is mapped to byte array and byte array is not comparable. The order of operations in the database is absolutely out of your control. You cannot base your logic on expected order in which the entities will be updated. You can do it only if your pages and book will be saved by two different `SaveChanges` calls. In such case you cannot use `OnPropertyChanges` at all and you must handle `Book` change manually before you make any change to your pages.

Comment: I have a computed column which converts 'binary' to 'bigint'. So comparison is not a problem.. as for the ordering, I lean towards not relying on it too. So I would consider this approach as no-go. Thanks